# Render Text into ITK Image

Tags: image-processing, itk

Is it possible to render text to an ITK image without including VTK? What I want to do is print some labels into an image without having to add this huge VTK Library.

The only solution I found is to use Freetype and VTK to do that.

```
//Properties of the Text  
vtkSmartPointer<vtkTextProperty> textPropertyRegion = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTextProperty>::New();
    textPropertyRegion->SetColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    textPropertyRegion->SetFontSize(36);
    textPropertyRegion->SetJustificationToCentered();
    textPropertyRegion->SetBold(1);
//Renders the Text 
vtkSmartPointer<vtkFreeTypeUtilities> freeType = vtkSmartPointer<vtkFreeTypeUtilities>::New();
//The text will be temporarily rendered into this image
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> textImage = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData>::New();
    freeType->RenderString(textPropertyRegion, vtkStdString("TEXT"), textImage );
int* featureImageDims = featureImage->GetDimensions();
// Set every pixel of the rendered Text Image into the main Image
for (int y = 0; y < featureImageDims[1]; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < featureImageDims[0]; x++) {

        unsigned char *valueText = static_cast<unsigned char*>(featureImage->GetScalarPointer(x, featureImageDims[1] - 1 - y, 0));

        itk::Image<short,2>::IndexType idx;
        idx.SetElement(0, x + 1200);
        idx.SetElement(1, y + 1000);

        RGBPixelType pix;
        pix.fill(valueText[0]);
        it.SetIndex(idx);
        it.Set(pix);
    }
}
```

This works, but: It's terrible to refactor and I need to include 2 additional libraries for the task to render a string and put it into the image. Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: It is possible without VTK but I'm afraid it isnt possible with ITK alone.

Comment: Do you know how I can do it without VTK?

Comment: OpenCV, if it appeals more, has some. In Windows, GDI is readily available, ...